# How to debug why systemd is idling and is not going on with the boot process?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, boot, systemd

I am trying to create a PV instance for AWS EC2.  The template VM is based on CentOS 7, which is using systemd.  The disk layout is two partitions: /boot (/dev/xvda1) and LVM2 (/dev/xvda2).  The root file system resides on LVM2.  When I launch the VM on my VirtualBox it starts up fine, but when I upload it to EC2 it loads up to the point where systemd initiates and completes the filesystem check, then it sits there forever.

So the question is how to squeeze more debugging output from systemd to figure out what it is waiting for?

Below is the log I got from console with systemd.debug (a bit truncated at the start since the body here is limited by 30K characters:

```
Xen Minimal OS!
Booting 'CentOS'



root (hd0,0)

 Filesystem type is xfs, partition type 0x83

kernel /vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=3d5995c8-0aef-4b6d-8eda-d56

cfce8455f ro rd.lvm.lv=vg0/root crashkernel=auto ipv6.disable=1 rootflags=uquot

a,gquota quiet systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=console log_buf_len=1

M console=tty0 console=hvc0 selinux=0

initrd /initramfs-3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64.img



============= Init TPM Front ================
Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error = ENOENT
Tpmfront:Info Shutting down tpmfront
close blk: backend=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/3587/51712 node=device/vbd/51712
[365350.528388] i8042: No controller found
[365350.603593] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset of type cgroup with options cpuset.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct of type cgroup with options cpu,cpuacct.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/memory of type cgroup with options memory.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/devices of type cgroup with options devices.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer of type cgroup with options freezer.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls of type cgroup with options net_cls.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio of type cgroup with options blkio.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event of type cgroup with options perf_event.
Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb of type cgroup with options hugetlb.
systemd 208 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ)
Detected virtualization 'xen'.
Running in initial RAM disk.
Set hostname to <centos.template>.
Using cgroup controller name=systemd. File system hierarchy is at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd.
Installed release agent.
Using notification socket @/org/freedesktop/systemd1/notify
Set up TFD_TIMER_CANCEL_ON_SET timerfd.
Successfully created private D-Bus server.
Spawned /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator as 62
Spawned /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dracut-rootfs-generator as 63
/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator exited successfully.
/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dracut-rootfs-generator exited successfully.
Looking for unit files in (higher priority first):
    /etc/systemd/system
    /run/systemd/system
    /run/systemd/generator
    /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
    /usr/lib/systemd/system
Looking for SysV init scripts in:
    /etc/rc.d/init.d
Looking for SysV rcN.d links in:
    /etc/rc.d
Failed to load configuration for syslog.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for plymouth-start.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for systemd-readahead-replay.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for systemd-readahead-collect.service: No such file or directory
-.mount changed dead -> mounted
Activating default unit: default.target
Failed to load configuration for systemd-fsck-root.service: No such file or directory
Trying to enqueue job initrd.target/start/isolate
Installed new job initrd.target/start as 1
Installed new job basic.target/start as 2
Installed new job sysinit.target/start as 3
Installed new job local-fs.target/start as 4
Installed new job swap.target/start as 6
Installed new job systemd-modules-load.service/start as 7
Installed new job systemd-ask-password-console.path/start as 8
Installed new job systemd-journald.service/start as 9
Installed new job systemd-journald.socket/start as 10
Installed new job systemd-udevd.service/start as 11
Installed new job systemd-udevd-control.socket/start as 12
Installed new job systemd-udevd-kernel.socket/start as 13
Installed new job systemd-udev-trigger.service/start as 14
Installed new job kmod-static-nodes.service/start as 15
Installed new job systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service/start as 16
Installed new job systemd-sysctl.service/start as 17
Installed new job sockets.target/start as 20
Installed new job timers.target/start as 21
Installed new job paths.target/start as 22
Installed new job slices.target/start as 23
Installed new job -.slice/start as 24
Installed new job system.slice/start as 25
Installed new job initrd-root-fs.target/start as 26
Installed new job sysroot.mount/start as 27
Installed new job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service/start as 28
Installed new job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.device/start as 29
Installed new job initrd-fs.target/start as 31
Installed new job initrd-parse-etc.service/start as 32
Installed new job dracut-cmdline.service/start as 33
Installed new job dracut-initqueue.service/start as 34
Installed new job dracut-mount.service/start as 35
Installed new job dracut-pre-mount.service/start as 36
Installed new job dracut-pre-pivot.service/start as 37
Installed new job dracut-pre-trigger.service/start as 38
Installed new job dracut-pre-udev.service/start as 39
Enqueued job initrd.target/start as 1
Loaded units and determined initial transaction in 112.443ms.
-.slice changed dead -> active
Job -.slice/start finished, result=done
system.slice changed dead -> active
Job system.slice/start finished, result=done
slices.target changed dead -> active
Job slices.target/start finished, result=done
timers.target changed dead -> active
Job timers.target/start finished, result=done
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/sys succeeded for systemd-udevd-kernel.socket.
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket changed dead -> listening
Job systemd-udevd-kernel.socket/start finished, result=done
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/sys succeeded for systemd-udevd-control.socket.
systemd-udevd-control.socket changed dead -> listening
Job systemd-udevd-control.socket/start finished, result=done
systemd-journald.socket changed dead -> listening
Job systemd-journald.socket/start finished, result=done
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|noresume failed for dracut-cmdline.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|resume failed for dracut-cmdline.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.break=cmdline failed for dracut-cmdline.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/lib/dracut/hooks/cmdline succeeded for dracut-cmdline.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/etc/cmdline.d/*.conf failed for dracut-cmdline.service.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/initrd-release succeeded for dracut-cmdline.service.
About to execute: /bin/dracut-cmdline
Forked /bin/dracut-cmdline as 80
dracut-cmdline.service changed dead -> start
ConditionPathExists=/lib/modules/3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64/modules.devname succeeded for kmod-static-nodes.service.
ConditionCapability=CAP_MKNOD succeeded for kmod-static-nodes.service.
About to execute: /usr/bin/mkdir -p /run/tmpfiles.d
Forked /usr/bin/mkdir as 81
kmod-static-nodes.service changed dead -> start-pre
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/run/sysctl.d failed for systemd-sysctl.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/etc/sysctl.d succeeded for systemd-sysctl.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/usr/local/lib/sysctl.d failed for systemd-sysctl.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/usr/lib/sysctl.d succeeded for systemd-sysctl.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/lib/sysctl.d succeeded for systemd-sysctl.service.
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/proc/sys/ succeeded for systemd-sysctl.service.
About to execute: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl
Forked /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl as 82
systemd-sysctl.service changed dead -> start
sockets.target changed dead -> active
Job sockets.target/start finished, result=done
About to execute: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
Forked /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald as 83
systemd-journald.service changed dead -> running
Job systemd-journald.service/start finished, result=done
dracut-cmdline[80]: Executing: /bin/dracut-cmdline
systemd-journald.socket changed listening -> running
ConditionPathExists=!/run/plymouth/pid succeeded for systemd-ask-password-console.path.
systemd-ask-password-console.path changed dead -> waiting
Job systemd-ask-password-console.path/start finished, result=done
paths.target changed dead -> active
Job paths.target/start finished, result=done
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.modules-load failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|modules-load failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/run/modules-load.d failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/etc/modules-load.d failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/usr/local/lib/modules-load.d failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/usr/lib/modules-load.d failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/lib/modules-load.d failed for systemd-modules-load.service.
ConditionCapability=CAP_SYS_MODULE succeeded for systemd-modules-load.service.
Starting of systemd-modules-load.service requested but condition failed. Ignoring.
Job systemd-modules-load.service/start finished, result=done
swap.target changed dead -> active
Job swap.target/start finished, result=done
local-fs.target changed dead -> active
Job local-fs.target/start finished, result=done
Set up jobs progress timerfd.
Set up idle_pipe watch.
Received SIGCHLD from PID 62 (n/a).
Child 81 (mkdir) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 81 belongs to kmod-static-nodes.service
kmod-static-nodes.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
kmod-static-nodes.service got final SIGCHLD for state start-pre
About to execute: /usr/bin/kmod static-nodes --format=tmpfiles --output=/run/tmpfiles.d/kmod.conf
Forked /usr/bin/kmod as 149
kmod-static-nodes.service changed start-pre -> start
Child 82 (systemd-sysctl) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 82 belongs to systemd-sysctl.service
systemd-sysctl.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd-sysctl.service changed start -> exited
Job systemd-sysctl.service/start finished, result=done
systemd-sysctl.service: cgroup is empty
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got notification message for unit systemd-journald.service
systemd-journald.service: Got message
systemd-journald.service: got STATUS=Processing requests...
Got notification message for unit systemd-journald.service
systemd-journald.service: Got message
systemd-journald.service: got STATUS=Processing requests...
Accepted connection on private bus.
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Received SIGCHLD from PID 149 (kmod).
Child 149 (kmod) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 149 belongs to kmod-static-nodes.service
kmod-static-nodes.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
kmod-static-nodes.service changed start -> exited
Job kmod-static-nodes.service/start finished, result=done
kmod-static-nodes.service: cgroup is empty
ConditionCapability=CAP_MKNOD succeeded for systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service.
About to execute: /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --prefix=/dev --create
Forked /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles as 151
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service changed dead -> start
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Received SIGCHLD from PID 151 (systemd-tmpfile).
Child 151 (systemd-tmpfile) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 151 belongs to systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service changed start -> exited
Job systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service/start finished, result=done
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: cgroup is empty
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Received SIGCHLD from PID 80 (dracut-cmdline).
Child 80 (dracut-cmdline) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 80 belongs to dracut-cmdline.service
dracut-cmdline.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
dracut-cmdline.service changed start -> exited
Job dracut-cmdline.service/start finished, result=done
dracut-cmdline.service: cgroup is empty
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.driver.post failed for dracut-pre-udev.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.driver.pre failed for dracut-pre-udev.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.driver.blacklist failed for dracut-pre-udev.service.
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.break=pre-udev failed for dracut-pre-udev.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/lib/dracut/hooks/pre-udev succeeded for dracut-pre-udev.service.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/initrd-release succeeded for dracut-pre-udev.service.
About to execute: /bin/dracut-pre-udev
Forked /bin/dracut-pre-udev as 161
dracut-pre-udev.service changed dead -> start
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
dracut-pre-udev[161]: Executing: /bin/dracut-pre-udev
Incoming traffic on systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket changed listening -> running
Received SIGCHLD from PID 161 (dracut-pre-udev).
Child 161 (dracut-pre-udev) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 161 belongs to dracut-pre-udev.service
dracut-pre-udev.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
dracut-pre-udev.service changed start -> exited
Job dracut-pre-udev.service/start finished, result=done
dracut-pre-udev.service: cgroup is empty
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/sys succeeded for systemd-udevd.service.
About to execute: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
Forked /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd as 190
systemd-udevd.service changed dead -> start
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Got notification message for unit systemd-udevd.service
systemd-udevd.service: Got message
systemd-udevd.service: got READY=1
systemd-udevd.service changed start -> running
Job systemd-udevd.service/start finished, result=done
systemd-udevd-control.socket changed listening -> running
Got notification message for unit systemd-udevd.service
systemd-udevd.service: Got message
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.break=pre-trigger failed for dracut-pre-trigger.service.
ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=|/lib/dracut/hooks/pre-trigger failed for dracut-pre-trigger.service.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/initrd-release succeeded for dracut-pre-trigger.service.
Starting of dracut-pre-trigger.service requested but condition failed. Ignoring.
Job dracut-pre-trigger.service/start finished, result=done
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/sys succeeded for systemd-udev-trigger.service.
About to execute: /usr/bin/udevadm trigger --type=subsystems --action=add
Forked /usr/bin/udevadm as 191
systemd-udev-trigger.service changed dead -> start
Received SIGCHLD from PID 191 (udevadm).
Child 191 (udevadm) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 191 belongs to systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemd-udev-trigger.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd-udev-trigger.service running next main command for state start
About to execute: /usr/bin/udevadm trigger --type=devices --action=add
Forked /usr/bin/udevadm as 198
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
systemd-udev-trigger.service: cgroup is empty
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
sys-module-configfs.device changed dead -> plugged
Trying to enqueue job sys-kernel-config.mount/start/fail
Installed new job sys-kernel-config.mount/start as 40
Enqueued job sys-kernel-config.mount/start as 40
ConditionPathExists=/sys/kernel/config succeeded for sys-kernel-config.mount.
About to execute: /bin/mount configfs /sys/kernel/config -t configfs
Forked /bin/mount as 201
sys-kernel-config.mount changed dead -> mounting
Received SIGCHLD from PID 198 (udevadm).
Child 198 (udevadm) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 198 belongs to systemd-udev-trigger.service
systemd-udev-trigger.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd-udev-trigger.service changed start -> exited
Job systemd-udev-trigger.service/start finished, result=done
systemd-udev-trigger.service: cgroup is empty
ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.break=initqueue failed for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/timeout/*.sh succeeded for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/online/*.sh failed for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh succeeded for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/settled/*.sh failed for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExistsGlob=|/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/*.sh succeeded for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExists=|/lib/dracut/need-initqueue succeeded for dracut-initqueue.service.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/initrd-release succeeded for dracut-initqueue.service.
About to execute: /bin/dracut-initqueue
Forked /bin/dracut-initqueue as 202
dracut-initqueue.service changed dead -> start
Accepted connection on private bus.
dev-ttyS0.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS0.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS1.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS2.device changed dead -> plugged
dracut-initqueue[202]: Executing: /bin/dracut-initqueue
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS2.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS3.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS3.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc1.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc1.device changed dead -> plugged
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
dev-hvc0.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc0.device changed dead -> plugged
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
dev-hvc3.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc3.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-kernel-config.mount changed mounting -> mounting-done
Job sys-kernel-config.mount/start finished, result=done
sysinit.target changed dead -> active
Job sysinit.target/start finished, result=done
basic.target changed dead -> active
Job basic.target/start finished, result=done
Received SIGCHLD from PID 201 (mount).
Child 201 (mount) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 201 belongs to sys-kernel-config.mount
sys-kernel-config.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=0
sys-kernel-config.mount changed mounting-done -> mounted
dev-hvc2.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc2.device changed dead -> plugged
Accepted connection on private bus.
dev-hvc4.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc4.device changed dead -> plugged
Accepted connection on private bus.
dev-hvc5.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc5.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc7.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc7.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc6.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc6.device changed dead -> plugged
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.Reload() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1
Reloading.
Serializing state to /run/systemd/dump-1-NXMDvr
Spawned /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator as 215
Spawned /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dracut-rootfs-generator as 216
/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator exited successfully.
/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/dracut-rootfs-generator exited successfully.
Looking for unit files in (higher priority first):
    /etc/systemd/system
    /run/systemd/system
    /run/systemd/generator
    /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
    /usr/lib/systemd/system
Looking for SysV init scripts in:
    /etc/rc.d/init.d
Looking for SysV rcN.d links in:
    /etc/rc.d
Failed to load configuration for syslog.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for systemd-readahead-replay.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for systemd-readahead-collect.service: No such file or directory
Failed to load configuration for plymouth-start.service: No such file or directory
Deserializing state...
Failed to load configuration for systemd-fsck-root.service: No such file or directory
Reinstalled deserialized job initrd.target/start as 1
Reinstalled deserialized job initrd-root-fs.target/start as 26
Reinstalled deserialized job initrd-fs.target/start as 31
Reinstalled deserialized job initrd-parse-etc.service/start as 32
Reinstalled deserialized job dracut-initqueue.service/start as 34
Reinstalled deserialized job dracut-mount.service/start as 35
Reinstalled deserialized job dracut-pre-mount.service/start as 36
Reinstalled deserialized job dracut-pre-pivot.service/start as 37
Reinstalled deserialized job sysroot.mount/start as 27
Reinstalled deserialized job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service/start as 28
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS0.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS0.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS1.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS2.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS2.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS3.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-ttyS3.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc0.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc0.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc1.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc1.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc2.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc2.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc3.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc3.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc4.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc4.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc5.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc5.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc6.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc6.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-devices-virtual-tty-hvc7.device changed dead -> plugged
dev-hvc7.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-module-configfs.device changed dead -> plugged
sys-kernel-config.mount changed dead -> mounted
sysinit.target changed dead -> active
systemd-journald.socket changed dead -> running
system.slice changed dead -> active
slices.target changed dead -> active
-.slice changed dead -> active
sockets.target changed dead -> active
systemd-journald.service changed dead -> running
systemd-udevd-control.socket changed dead -> running
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket changed dead -> running
systemd-udevd.service changed dead -> running
local-fs.target changed dead -> active
swap.target changed dead -> active
systemd-ask-password-console.path changed dead -> waiting
systemd-udev-trigger.service changed dead -> exited
kmod-static-nodes.service changed dead -> exited
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service changed dead -> exited
systemd-sysctl.service changed dead -> exited
paths.target changed dead -> active
-.mount changed dead -> mounted
basic.target changed dead -> active
dracut-cmdline.service changed dead -> exited
dracut-initqueue.service changed dead -> start
dracut-pre-udev.service changed dead -> exited
timers.target changed dead -> active
Closing left-over fd 35
Closing left-over fd 36
About to execute: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck /dev/disk/by-uuid/3d5995c8-0aef-4b6d-8eda-d56cfce8455f
Forked /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck as 227
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service changed dead -> start
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Received SIGCHLD from PID 215 (n/a).
systemd-fsck[227]: Executing: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck /dev/disk/by-uuid/3d5995c8-0aef-4b6d-8eda-d56cfce8455f
systemd-fsck[227]: fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/disk/by-uuid/3d5995c8-0aef-4b6d-8eda-d56cfce8455f
Received SIGCHLD from PID 227 (systemd-fsck).
Child 227 (systemd-fsck) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Child 227 belongs to systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service changed start -> exited
Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service/start finished, result=done
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d5995c8\x2d0aef\x2d4b6d\x2d8eda\x2dd56cfce8455f.service: cgroup is empty
Accepted connection on private bus.
Accepted connection on private bus.
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent.Released() on /org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
Got D-Bus request: org.freedesktop.DBus.Local.Disconnected() on /org/freedesktop/DBus/Local
```

Comment: Well, it turned out that the initramfs was missing Xen frontend modules (specifically the block device module).  This was found by brainstorming the boot process.  Still, I'd prefer to see a way how you can get this information from the first glance on the hung system (like it was with old, good SysV init).  Generally, I like the ideas behind systemd, but this particular issue of spending too much time debugging the hung boot process is killing it.